# Faster and more pythonic way to reproduce unique set of unordered random numbers inside nested list

Tags: python, arrays

I wanted to create a domino game. I'm in the beginning of my journey to become a python dev.
I have made enough progress but I'm wondering if i could **refactor** my unique set generator function more elegant - **pythonic** and shorter.
This is my function and i think it is working as it should be. All the other functions in the program are depended on this.

The main job of the function is creating a list of unique set of two random numbers (0-6(including)) range and all of those lists are inside a list.
For ex. [1,2] and [2,1] are the same and should appear only once in the final array.

```
from random import randrange

length = 28


def unique_set_generator(set_size):
    unique_set = set()
    main_set = []
    while len(unique_set) != set_size:
        x, y = randrange(7), randrange(7)
        if (x, y) not in unique_set and (y, x) not in unique_set:
            unique_set.add((x, y))
    
    set_to_list = list(unique_set)

    for i in range(set_size):
        main_set.append(list(set_to_list[i]))

    return main_set


print(unique_set_generator(length))
```

Outcome:
`[[4, 3], [5, 4], [2, 2], [1, 0], [1, 3], [6, 5], [4, 2], [3, 3], [5, 0], [3, 6], [5, 3], [1, 2], [0, 4], [1, 5], [6, 1], [6, 4], [3, 2], [5, 2], [4, 4], [5, 5], [0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 3], [2, 0], [1, 4], [2, 6], [6, 0], [6, 6]]`

Comment: The easiest way is to create the list in order, and then use `random.shuffle` to shuffle them.

Comment: General review and critique of working code is off-topic on StackOverflow. You may be able to post on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to check their content guidelines before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tools Python provides:

```
import random

dominos = [(i,j) for i in range(7) for j in range(i,7)]
print(dominos)
random.shuffle(dominos)
print(dominos)
```